# Aggregate 2 vacation periods into one if they are separated by the same weekend in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

This is my first question on the platform and I am beginning the SQL journey! :D
I have a bit of a problem with my code and i do not know what I overlooked

I have a table 'Vacations' with 3 columns in Mysql
marca, which is unique code for a person's name
start_date which is the first day of his vacation
and end_date which is the last one.

This is a portion of my table:

| marca | start_date | end_date |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 750001 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-25 |  |
| 750001 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-10-15 |  |
| 750002 | 2022-03-30 | 2022-03-30 |  |
| 750002 | 2022-04-09 | 2022-04-10 |  |
| 750002 | 2022-06-15 | 2022-06-29 |  |
| 750003 | 2022-02-20 | 2022-02-20 |  |
| 750003 | 2022-05-16 | 2022-05-20 | (16-20 it's Monday to Friday) |
| 750003 | 2022-05-23 | 2022-05-27 | (same) |
| 750003 | 2022-05-30 | 2022-06-03 | (same) |
| 750003 | 2022-06-06 | 2022-06-07 | (Monday and Tuesday) |
| 750003 | 2022-08-02 | 2022-08-23 |  |
| 750003 | 2022-08-23 | 2022-08-25 |  |

I need to see which people exceeds 10 free days.
Some people have it clear how they have it, like 750001
But some people have vacation from Monday to Friday and then again starting with the next Monday.
Therefor, I want my code to take in consideration that and combine those 2 (or more) segments of vacation that are separated by the same weekend and also if the next start_date is exactly the next day after the last end_date to combine them.

So the resulting table should be looking like:

| marca | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 750001 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-25 |
| 750001 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-10-15 |
| 750002 | 2022-06-15 | 2022-06-29 |
| 750003 | 2022-05-16 | 2022-06-07 |
| 750003 | 2022-08-02 | 2022-08-25 |

This is the code:

```sql
SELECT marca, start_date, end_date
FROM (
    SELECT marca, start_date,
        CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%W') = 'Friday' AND DATE_FORMAT(LEAD(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY marca ORDER BY start_date), '%W') = 'Monday'
                 AND DATEDIFF(LEAD(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY marca ORDER BY start_date), end_date) = 3
             THEN LEAD(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY marca ORDER BY start_date)
             ELSE end_date
        END AS end_date
    FROM vacations
) AS subquery
WHERE start_date <= end_date
ORDER BY marca, start_date;
```

It doesn't do nothing :(

Comment: Can you create a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) with your example data and query?

Answer (score 0):

Your current query does exactly what you have asked of it. It extends the `end_date` of the `CURRENT ROW` to that of the `LEAD ROW` when the conditions are met:

| marca | start_date | orig_end_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 750001 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-25 |
| 750001 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-10-15 | 2022-10-15 |
| 750002 | 2022-03-30 | 2022-03-30 | 2022-03-30 |
| 750002 | 2022-04-09 | 2022-04-10 | 2022-04-10 |
| 750002 | 2022-06-15 | 2022-06-29 | 2022-06-29 |
| 750003 | 2022-02-20 | 2022-02-20 | 2022-02-20 |
| 750003 | 2022-05-16 | **2022-05-20** | **2022-05-27** |
| 750003 | 2022-05-23 | **2022-05-27** | **2022-06-03** |
| 750003 | 2022-05-30 | **2022-06-03** | **2022-06-07** |
| 750003 | 2022-06-06 | 2022-06-07 | 2022-06-07 |
| 750003 | 2022-08-02 | 2022-08-23 | 2022-08-23 |
| 750003 | 2022-08-23 | 2022-08-25 | 2022-08-25 |

One approach to this problem is to treat it as a [gaps-and-islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+gaps-and-islands) problem, as you are looking for sequences of consecutive free days.

We start by creating a list of all dates we are interested in:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE calendar (dt) AS (
    SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM vacations
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM calendar WHERE dt < (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM vacations)
)
```

**Note**: [cte_max_recursion_depth](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_cte_max_recursion_depth) has a default value of 1000, causing the CTE to terminate when it recurses past 1000 levels. You can read more here - [Limiting Common Table Expression Recursion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursion-limits).

If you are running this query for a period greater than 1000 days you will need to increase the recursion depth:

```sql
SET SESSION cte_max_recursion_depth = 10000;
```

We can then `CROSS JOIN` the calendar to a distinct list of the employees we are interested in (I have used a DISTINCT query on the vacations table), and then `LEFT JOIN` to vacations to get a full list of when employees have a `free_day`, either because they are on vacation or it is a weekend day (`v.id IS NOT NULL OR WEEKDAY(c.dt) IN (5, 6)`).

To look for sequences of consecutive free-days we are using `c.dt - INTERVAL (DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e.marca ORDER BY c.dt)) DAY` which can be illustrated by:

| dt | dense_rank | dt - INTERVAL (dense_rank) DAY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-03 | 1 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-05 | 3 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-05 | 3 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-06 | 4 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-07 | 5 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-19 | 6 | 2022-01-13 |
| 2022-01-20 | 7 | 2022-01-13 |

[ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) is commonly used for the above grouping but, due to your example having an employee with two vacation entries for the same date (750003, 2022-08-23), we need to use [DENSE_RANK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) instead.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE calendar (dt) AS (
    SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM vacations
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM calendar WHERE dt < (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM vacations)
),
free_days AS (
    SELECT c.dt, e.marca, v.start_date, v.end_date,
        c.dt - INTERVAL (DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e.marca ORDER BY c.dt)) DAY AS free_day_grp
    FROM calendar c
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT marca FROM vacations) e
    LEFT JOIN vacations v
        ON c.dt BETWEEN v.start_date AND v.end_date
        AND e.marca = v.marca
    WHERE v.id IS NOT NULL OR WEEKDAY(c.dt) IN (5, 6)
)
SELECT marca, MIN(start_date) AS start_date, MAX(end_date) AS end_date
FROM free_days
GROUP BY marca, free_day_grp
HAVING DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date) + 1 > 10;

-- Obviously, the HAVING clause could be written as
-- HAVING DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date) > 9;
```

Output:

| marca | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 750001 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-25 |
| 750001 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-10-15 |
| 750002 | 2022-06-15 | 2022-06-29 |
| 750003 | 2022-05-16 | 2022-06-07 |
| 750003 | 2022-08-02 | 2022-08-25 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EH-gpP7D)

Answer (score 0):

Following should list any date sequence that extends or overlaps a prior vacation.  Merging the two so you see both is an enhancement you should be able to do from this:

```
WITH t1 AS(
    SELECT marca
         , CASE DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%W')
               WHEN 'Sunday' THEN DATE_ADD(start_date,interval -1 day)
               WHEN 'Monday' THEN DATE_ADD(start_date,interval -2 day)
               ELSE start_date
           END AS start_date
         , CASE DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%W')
               WHEN 'Friday' THEN DATE_ADD(end_date, interval 2 day)
               WHEN 'Saturday' THEN DATE_ADD(end_date, interval 1 day)
           ELSE end_date END AS end_date
    FROM vacations )
SELECT * 
FROM   t1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM t1 sub
    WHERE  sub.marca=t1.marca
       AND sub.end_date BETWEEN t1.start_date AND t1.end_date
       AND sub.start_date <> t1.start_date
     );
```

It works by adjusting every start date that is Sunday or Monday to the preceding Saturday date... and converting every end date that is Friday or Saturday to the following Sunday date.   Then, it looks for instances where there's an overlap in dates (which there will be in your problem case).